# How to check whether a view already exists in my Application Window?

Tags: ios, swift, uiview

```
class func showNotificationWithTitleWarning(controller:UIViewController,title :String, subtitle :String){

        let subtitle = subtitle
        var isTrue : Bool = false


        //let horizontalPadding:CGFloat = 0.0
        let deviceWidth:CGFloat = Device.DeviceWidth
        //let deviceHeight:CGFloat = Device.DeviceHeight
        let height:CGFloat = 64.0

        let contentFrame:CGRect = CGRectMake(0,0 , deviceWidth ,height)

        var toastView:CustomTopNotification!
               toastView = CustomTopNotification(frame:contentFrame,Str_title:subtitle)

        if  toastView.superview === UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate?.window!! {


                        toastView.removeFromSuperview()
            print("Already there")

        } else {
            UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate?.window!!.addSubview(toastView)


            toastView.frame.origin.y = -80

            UIView.animateWithDuration(0.2, delay: 0.0, options: UIViewAnimationOptions.CurveEaseOut, animations: {
                toastView.frame.origin.y =  0
                controller.view.layoutIfNeeded()

                },completion: {_ in

            })

        }

    }
```

This is my block of code. However, it never enters the if block. The thing I want to achieve is to not add the view continuously if it already exists there. If the view already exists in the application window,I want it to do nothing. However, it is adding the view everytime the action is being called. I have tried mostly every solution proposed like isdescendantOf(),subviews.contains().. But none has worked so far

Comment: try to make it a instance function and make the toast a instance var, and remove it from superview before adding it in subview again then

Comment: Could you please post some source code to do it?

Comment: can you tell which class this function is in ?

Comment: This function is inside a custom Class CustomNotification. ToastView is of type CustomTopNotification which is a custom class of type UIView

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change your code to the following

```
class CustomNotification  {
   static let sharedInstance = CustomNotification()

   private var toastView: CustomTopNotification?
   func showNotificationWithTitleWarning(controller:UIViewController,title :String, subtitle :String){
            if let prevToastView = toastView {
                  prevToastView.removeFromSuperView()
            }
           //prev code of function here
           // change only one line in it
            toastView:CustomTopNotification!
               toastView = CustomTopNotification(frame:contentFrame,Str_title:subtitle)
        }
}
```

Now call your notification from anywhere like

```
CustomNotification.sharedInstance.showNotificationWithTitleWarning()
```

Comment: = is not working. And now the view doesn't display at all

Comment: which line = ? `if let prevToastView =`  or the `toastView =`

Comment: Thank You .. after correcting all my silly mistakes, it finally worked :)

Answer (score 0):

Try checking that `toastView` has superview or not. If not , then add it. Following `if` condition executes when `toastView` has not added on any view.

```
if  ! toastView.superview
```

Comment: Checking whether toastView has superview or not is not possible with this code in swift

Answer (score 0):

You can set a tag to this view and can get "viewWithTag:" if it is returning view that means it is already added